# Can I fix noindex errors in Google Search Console for webp images?

Tags: google-search-console, images, noindex

Google Search Console is showing a noindex error for my images in the WEBP image format, and I don't know how to fix this problem.

1. Does this type of noindex error cause any problems?
2. How can I get this photo format to be indexed?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the Meta Tags of the URL (where the image is present) and I found no relevant information added around the image.

Please check the screenshot below:

[image: Image Crawled Currently Not Indexed]

As you can see, the description of the image is missing, the lang attribute is missing, and more.

Make sure to add relevant information for the image. The image is crawled but Google doesn't find it informational or helpful to index it.

Comment: Thanks for your answering. How should I add Lang attribute and other attribute for image?